# App to pull env. variables when running locally, but EC2 instance credentials when running on ECS cluster?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, boto3, amazon-ecs

I have an app that I am running on an ECS cluster. While running on the cluster, I want it to pull its credentials from the IAM profile metadata inherent in the EC2 box. However, as I develop the app, I run it locally where my docker containers/computer do not have the same profile credentials. To run locally, I pass environment variables.

Is there an easy way to code my `constants.py` file so that the app can tell if I am running locally or on the cluster? My hope is that the app can toggle from pulling locally configured environment variables (when running locally) to pulling instance credentials (when running on the cluster) so that I don't have to change the code every time I want to push something to production/the cluster.

Here is the code from my constants.py I use to pull the environment variables and the instance credentials respectively. I would like to be able to toggle without commenting/uncommenting every time I switch environments.

```
##################local version:
AWS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_KEY']

################## cluster version:
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials() #with no config file in place so that it pulls from the instance metadata
AWS_KEY=credentials.access_key
AWS_SECRET_KEY=credentials.secret_key
```

Those keys are then imported into various parts of the app to perform queries/s3 pulls/elastic search requests, etc.

Comment: Have you considered setting some additional env variable, say `LOCAL_BOX=1`, and checking its status in the script?

Comment: Normally you woudn't be doing this. boto3 gets credentails based on [priority rules](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/guide/configuration.html). So it should transparently detect which credentials to use in which environment.

Comment: @Marcin you are right it pulls based on priority rules. However, on the ecs cluster there are no environment variables for aws key, etc. causing it to fail unless I comment out those lines.

Comment: @Oleksii Donoha, that is a good idea. And then couch the two portions of code in a try/except block?

Comment: I don't see the need for `try ... except`, I would probably do `if "LOCAL_BOX" not in os.environ: ...`

Comment: @JoeBanks On ECS you use [task roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) which server same purpose as instance roles. Thus boto3 will take its permissions from the task role. That's the good practice of how you should be passing credentials to your tasks.

Comment: @Marin, Could you take a look at this post as well? It provides more context of what i'm thinking specifically : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646560/how-to-use-python-elasticsearch-package-with-ecs-instance-role-instead-of-passin